# ruby - reading string into array/subarray

Tags: ruby

I am looking for a good way to convert string like:

```
"[apples, oranges, [strawberries, peas, grapes]]"
```

into an array which will look like:

```
array = [apples, oranges, [strawberries, peas, grapes]].
```

therefore `array[0] = ["apples"]`, `array[1] = ["oranges"]`, and `array[2] = ["strawberries", "peas", "grapes"]`

So, whenever in my string I have another inner square brackets, the content between brackets will be a subarray of my base array.

Comment: If `array = [apples, oranges, [strawberries, peas, grapes]]`, then `array[0]` is not `["apples"]`, nor is it `"apples"`, but is whatever value that is assigned to the variable `apples`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eval s.gsub /\w+/, '"\&"'
```

or, for an alternative result that might be useful...

```
eval s.gsub /\w+/, ':\&'
```

Now, these are vulnerable to [code injection exploits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) if you are not in full control of the input, so you could install [a JSON gem](http://flori.github.com/json/) and do something like this:

```
require 'json'

JSON.parse s.gsub /\w+/, '"\&"'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) to wrap the words in quotes and then [`eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) the string:

```
eval str.gsub(/\w+/) { |match| "'#{match}'" }
```

This assumes that your words are words in the sense of a regex: alphanumeric. Further, this is quick-and-dirty, and I don't recommend using `eval` if it can be avoided (by, for example, having your input be in a parseable serialization language) as it can be a security risk.

Comment: Depending on the environment in which this would be used, I would advise you not to do this. Eval is considered evil ;-). There are lots of things that can go wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, if your strings would be surrounded by "" it would be easier, than you could just use a JSON parser ;-). But for this you would have to write your own parser. There are different parser generator gems for ruby. E.g.

Parslet: http://kschiess.github.com/parslet/

Treetop: http://treetop.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Please don't include signatures in answers/questions, there's no need for them as your user profile like is right there with your answer. It just takes up more space and makes parsing text more difficult.